# Firebase function createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not being called within my custom function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, firebase-authentication, onclick

The function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is not being called within `SignUpUser` function when `onClick` event happening. But when I do `onClick={signUpUser(email,password)}` it works

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { signUpUser } from '../firebase';

function SignUpComponent() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    return (
        <AuthForm>
            <input type="text" 
            placeholder="Email" 
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="password" 
            name="password"
            placeholder="password" 
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <SubmitFormButton
            type="submit"  
            onClick={() => signUpUser(email,password)}
            >
            Sign Up
            </SubmitFormButton>
        </AuthForm>
    )
};
```

Here is my firebase.js file

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import {
    getAuth,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signInWithPopup,
    signOut,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ****,
    authDomain: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***"
};

  // Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
auth.useDeviceLanguage();

// Auth functions

export function signUpUser(email, password) {

    if (password.length < 6) {
          alert('Password is too short');
          return;
    };

  ˚˚createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      alert('Signed up Successfully', user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      alert(errorMessage);
      });
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `SubmitFormButton` to your post?

Comment: Dear Max. It is just a styled component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick={signUpUser(email,password)}`
Here the `signUpUser` is called during a render, no matter if clicked or not.

If it works that way and does not work with
 `onClick={() => signUpUser(email,password)}`
then there are no other options but your `SubmitFormButton` does not trigger `onClick`. Maybe it is not passed to the DOM at all.

Comment: Yozi, I believe you are correct. SubmitFormButton is a styled component not react component so it is probably do not implement the onClick event

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Auth form should implement **"onSubmit**" method. We should not call the function on the SubmitFormButton component